# Ubuntu cron cannot access shared folder in PHP script

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I am running a cron job on my PHP script. It consists of 4 stages.

1. Moving files to another location.
2. Reading an XML file.
3. Writing an ASCII file based on XML
4. Writing success or failure to DB

Now when I run the script from the URL it works fine, but when it runs as Cron job the script only runs the part 1 (about part 2 I don't know). It does not generate the file on part 3 and does not write do DB.

I have tried setting up the CRON as root, adminusername and www-data ut no luck.

The shared folder where file should be written is mounted with 0777 rights and as admin for the server.

What am I doing wrong?

```
45 14   * * *   www-data  php /var/www/block/xlm_reader/index.php
```

Comment: 1) You can use `curl` or `wget` and run your script by url.
2) Can you describe more information about your system and configuration?
2.1) Which permissions you use in your web app folder and files?
2.2) Are you sure that your script can be executed from console?
2.3) Are you sure that your console php.ini configuration is valid for your script?
Also check please error log

Comment: 3) Use the real path of php: /usr/bin/php in place of php.

Comment: Thanks. wget works fine and I made a wget cron job, now the whole thing works fine. I also changed the shared folders right on the windows server, so everyone ha sread and write rights. I think not using wget was the issue, since I was able to add/delete stuff with winscp with same admusr

Answer (score 0):

I think the cron cannot be executed because the owner of the process doesn't have enough permissions to reach the shared folder, and that includes the folder itself and the parent directories. All of them should be accesible by the user who's running the cron.

Comment: I tried runningthe cron as adminusr who should have the rights, since I can create and delete folders from the shared folder via. winscp with the same usr

Answer (score 0):

@Anton Ohorodnyk had the right idea. Using wget on cron and making sure that everyone had rights on the windows end of shared folder did the trick (Not sure if the usr rights mod. was even needed)